# Regex to match any words with the following condition: after the character %, it's allowed only to have %s or %.[0-9]f

Tags: java, regex, expression

Please help! I've searched and tried for hours with no success :(

`(?!.*%[^s]).*` : will match any thing and only `%s`

but

`(?!.*%\.[^0-9]f).*` : will not match things and `%.3f`

It's for me somehow not easy to combine them together.

Comment: Can you give example of input? And what you want to match and what you want to reject? It is not very clear from your question what you want.

Comment: It should match, for example: "abc %s xyz %.2f" and not match "abc %s %a" or not match "abc %s xyz %.ff njk %s ".

Comment: @TimLong: It looks like you are trying to check format string. Note that `%%` stands for literal `%`, so you might want to consider to allow that also.

Comment: Try removing the ^ characters from inside the square brackets.

Comment: Why shouldn't it match "abc %s %a"?  Because it doesn't have something like %.3f in it, or because it has %a in it?  It is very hard to figure out what you need just from a few examples; you need to tell us what the rules are, and it has to be precise--the title doesn't make it clear.

Comment: It should match, for example: "abc %s xyz %.2f" and not match "abc %s %a" or not match "abc %s xyz %.ff njk %s ". The Regex should match any combination of characters. And the only 2 groups of "%s" and "%.[0-9]f". No other combination of % with other characters is allowed to match. %a %1 %.s are rejected.

Comment: Is it OK if there's more than one %s, or more than one %.[0-9]f?  How about if there are no % signs at all?

Comment: @Tim Can you edit the question to express all these additional requirements please?  Someone who wants to help you shouldn't have to spend their time trawling through the comments to work out what you actually want.  Your question is far from clear.

Comment: @DavidWallace: i have tried to make the title clearer. <br/> @ all: thanks for your help! The right answer is F.J answer below.

Comment: Hang on - your question title talks about "words".  Does that mean that a % in the middle of a word is OK, even if it's not followed by s or .[0-9]f?  So foo%bar would be acceptable?  Please try to make your requirements clear in your question body.

Comment: @DavidWallace: i have again edited the title of the question. I hope others people will find it more understandable... Yes, "foo%bar" is also considered to be a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a double negative!

```
(?!.*%(?!s|\.[0-9]+f)).*
```

So the nested negative lookahead will cause the outer negative lookahead to fail if the `%` is followed by `s` or a valid float expression (like `%.3f`).

You may want to add a beginning of string anchor here to make sure you don't get partial matches.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/VTzJEUAlpb

Comment: You's got it! The problem's got solved in less than 10 minutes. Unbelievable :)

Answer (score 2):

Still not quite clear on the requirements, but maybe

```
(%s|%\.[0-9]+f|[^%])*
```

If % is followed by s or .<digits>f, this expression will match it.  Otherwise it matches only characters that aren't %, so that if % isn't followed by one of those, it will be rejected.  This regex must be matched against the entire input, so either use the `matches` method of `Matcher` or surround the above by `^` and `$`.  This allows any number of `%s` or `%.[0-9]+f` in the string.  If that's wrong, then the above won't work.

EDIT: if only one digit is allowed between `.` and `f` then remove the `+` from the above.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works also! The plus must be removed because only 1 digit is allowed.